# Change font in textarea

Tags: html

I'm trying to change the font that is displayed in a text area however, I don't want to use CSS in the `<head>` tags. Is it possible to not use CSS at all since I don't want it in the head tags? Will I need to import styling files?

Comment: Can you use external stylesheet file?

Comment: Or can you use `javascript` and add the rule on run-time using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is unnecessary, you can edit the font using inline CSS:

```
<textarea style="font-family:calibri"></textarea>
```

Comment: I think you mean `style=`, not `style:`